# Search single value in multiple columns with Linq.Dynamic.Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic-linq

My test case scenario is about a search textbox and a grid with the search results.

By using the following currently, i search only on the first column.

```
foreach (GridColumn s in columns)
{
   data = data.Where(string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", s.PropertyName), searchValue);
   break; 
}
```

As you already guessed, if i remove the break statement, no results are returned due to the lack of  `OR` statements between the `foreach` loop.

How can i search for a single value in multiple columns with `Linq.Dynamic.Core`?

Comment: how about, ``if (data != null && data.Any()){break;}``

Comment: @Sajid Still If the searchValue does not exist in the first column the foreach loop will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) you could use code like this:

```cs
var xx = new [] { "ax", "bx", "cy", "dz" };

var columns = new[] { "x", "y" };

string query = string.Join(" or ", columns.Select(c => $"it.Contains(\"{c}\")"));

var result = xx.AsQueryable().Where(query);
```

Example in LinqPad:
[image]